# PostgreSQL Getting Col1, Col2 when difference of them is maximum

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

Kindly keep your explanation beginner friendly.

I want to get max(col2-col1) and get col1, col2 of the row from which i got the max difference. How can i do that? Kindly provide explanation with the example code.

My code is kinda like below right now

```
select
   ......
   col1,  --It should be from the row from which we got the max
   col2,  --It should be from the row from which we got the max
   max(col2-col1)
   .....
joins
   ....
where
   conditions.....
group by
   reqColumns.....
```

Full code in [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/biryC3Lj).  Col1, Col2 and max() is c17, c18 and c19 respectively. Another thing is both the col1 and col2 is time expressed as string YYYYMMDDHH24MISS

Thanks is advance!!!

PS: Col2 can be empty string - `''`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: What about ties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select col1, col2, col2 - col1
from . . .
order by (col2 - col1) desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

If you want to treat `NULL` values as `0`, then use `COALESCE()`.

Comment: The thing i am doing right now is adding row number and fetching the row with row number 1 only. Will your code be faster than my implementation?
New code - https://pastebin.com/99KFWC6h

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do that :

```
SELECT col1, col2,max(abs(col1 - col2))
from test1
group by col1,col2
order by max(abs(col1 - col2)) desc
LIMIT 1
```

If not clear, let me know.

Comment: Thanks. Correct me if i am wrong, but wouldn't the query return only one row? I want col1,col2 and max() for each voucher in voucher column. Here is the link to full code in pastebin - https://pastebin.com/biryC3Lj . Col1, Col2 and max() is c17, c18 and c19 respectively.
Another thing is both the col1 and col2 is time expressed as string YYYYMMDDHH24MISS. For that i am first casting it to time stamp then getting the difference

Comment: I think you said beginner, but the code in pastebin.com is not :). If you want to add more details, please edit the original question, so others may help you.